# Package ros-hydro-pr2-common missing?

Tags: gazebo, pr2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm working through this [Gazebo tutorial](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials/?tut=ros_roslaunch), and I get to the point where we're told to do

> sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-pr2-common

However, apt-get comes back with "E: Unable to locate package ros-hydro-pr2-common". I'm running Indigo on Trusty, so I took a shot at

> sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-pr2-common

with the same result. My ros-latest.list points at

> deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu trusty main

It would seem that pr2_common just isn't there. I was able to build pr2_common from source (after chasing down ivcon and convex_decomposition), but I'm still wondering why apt-get couldn't find this package. Makes me think I've got something goofed-up in my setup.

Thanks,

Rick

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/191102/package-ros-hydro-pr2-common-missing?/) by [Rick Armstrong](https://answers.ros.org/users/13391/rick-armstrong/) on ROS Answers with karma: 567 on 2014-08-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There's nothing wrong with your system; the PR2 packages haven't been released into Indigo yet. You'll have to install them from source.

You can check the build and release status on the [Indigo Status Page](http://www.ros.org/debbuild/indigo.html?q=pr2)

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-08-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rick Armstrong](https://answers.ros.org/users/13391/rick-armstrong/) on 2014-08-24**:
Thanks, Austin.